# What is a "branch tip" in Git?

Tags: git, git-branch, terminology

I'm learning Git and reading the [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). The term "branch tip" is used sometimes in the book and also here on Stack Overflow, but I can't find the meaning of it.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A branch tip is the last commit or most recent commit on a branch. Basically it points to the most up to date code in the branch.

Comment: Are these branch tips sometimes referred to as branch heads?

Comment: @ScottyBlades No, these concepts are independent of each other. Think of the Git `HEAD` like the [head of a hard disk](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kenn-Oldham/publication/224323123/figure/fig8/AS:668490574884895@1536391981968/Mechanical-components-of-a-typical-hard-disk-drive.png), or the [needle on a record player](https://hackaday.com/2017/03/03/record-players-explained-for-the-streaming-generation/): `HEAD` is the current commit you are checked out on and reading data state from. When you check out a branch, the `HEAD` is **at** the tip of a branch.

Comment: Is there any difference between `a branch` and `the last commit of branch`?

Answer (score 11):

Using an image from the [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) to illustrate:

[image: Some branches in git]

The tip of the branch labeled `master` is commit `C2`, commit `C4` the tip of `hotfix`, while `C3` is the tip of `iss53`.

[Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16080357/1615903) is correct, but this might be easier to understand for beginners.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that C2, C3 and C4 are the "branch tips" of the branches named `master`, `hotfix` and `iss53`?

Comment: I think for a beginner your answer might even cause further confusion. You should either adopt @DavidRR's suggestion or add clarification, such as "In the above figure, the labels of `master`, `hotfix` ... all point to the tip of the respective branch".

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a "branch tip" in Git.

It's one of those unfortunate mistaken expressions that have leaked out from the Git book (and sometimes from the Git documentation as well) into common usage, but it's misleading and should be avoided.

---

The trouble is that a phrase like "branch tip" fosters the mistaken belief that a *branch* in Git has extension. It doesn't. A branch in Git is just a string name, and in particular it's a name for *one commit*.

In other words, a branch is not like a line; it's like a point. And the incorrect *belief* that it is like a line has caused more misunderstanding in the mind of Git users than just about any other.

So, for instance, in this diagram:

```
A <-- B <-- C <-- D (main)
       \
        X <-- Y <-- Z (mybranch)
```

... it is wrong to think of `mybranch` as somehow "being" X, Y, and Z. It's not. `mybranch` is Z (at this moment), and that's *all* it is.

What's true of X and Y is not that they are "on" the branch `mybranch`, as if `mybranch` had extension like a line, but rather that they are *reachable* from `mybranch` through the parent chain: Y is the parent of Z which *is* `mybranch`, and X is the parent of Y. (That's the significance of the backward-pointing arrows in the diagram.)

And this shows what's wrong with the whole idea of a branch as having extension. After all, B and A are *also* reachable from `mybranch` through the parent chain. Do you want to claim *they* are also "on" the branch `mybranch`? That is the sort of trouble you get into when you start using this kind of intuitive but false mental picture of what a branch is.

Sure, you could correct yourself and say that X and Y (and Z) are *reachable from `mybranch` but not from `main`* — and indeed it is correct and very useful to say that, and Git actually lets you say it quite easily. But for that very reason it is better to think *that* way, honestly and in line with what Git really is and how it works, than to make up some sort of false geometry in your head.

---

So, to conclude, there is no such thing as a "branch tip", because a branch is just one commit, and one commit cannot have a tip. What the book *means* by "branch tip" is actually *the branch* — the one commit pointed to by the branch name. It's a shortcut for saying "the commit pointed to by the branch name". But it's a bad shortcut, and I strongly advise against using it.

Comment: I thought like you too, but I found that the [Git glossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary) explains a bit differently(It says the branch 'head' is the one that points to a specific commit). What do you think about this? I think the Git official site does not rigorously define the terms and that makes beginners get confused.

Comment: See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ for more of how I think and talk about Git.

Comment: I looked it up and there's a lot of content! Thank you for the good article :)